# Email CNContact as vCard

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

Is it possible to convert `CNMutableContact` as an vCard by email ?
By below code I'm creating CNMutableContact and saving it to document directory but is it possible to send it directly instead of saving it? I don't need to save that.

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
    contact.givenName = "John"
    contact.familyName = "Doe"
    contact.emailAddresses = [
        CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: "john.doe@abc.com")
    ]
    let data = try! CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
    let s = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    if let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first{
        let fileURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("john.doe").appendingPathExtension("vcf")
        try! data.write(to: fileURL, options: [.atomicWrite])
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Code for send contact as vcard in Email.

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
   contact.givenName = "John"
   contact.familyName = "Doe"
   contact.emailAddresses = [
       CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: "john.doe@abc.com")
   ]
   let data = try! CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])

let mailComposer: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
           mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
           mailComposer.setSubject("emailsubject".localize())
           // mailComposer.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
           mailComposer.addAttachmentData(data), mimeType: "text/vcf", fileName: "contacts.vcf")
           self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```